# Can I edit the database to change a login?

Tags: users, login

I have WP installed on a server with a couple of other things. Naturally, phpMyAdmin is installed so I can edit my databases easily.

Anyway, is it possible to, using phpMyAdmin to edit a row and change the username? AFAIK everything is based off an ID, so why does this matter that you can't change it? Will it bork anything if I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can edit this without anything breaking.

There is nowhere in the dashboard to edit your username later so for many users who don't know or don't have access to the database this wont be possible for them, hence the warning when installing WordPress.

For those comfortable working in MySQL, it will be under the wp_users table in your database.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why you can't change username is because of multisite where network admin is defined by username and not ID. If there is another reason I have no idea what it is.